# "Develop method by which to see electronic display in sun-light", help me to make this engineering question into physics

Tags: discussion

I would like to be able to see a display such as computer screen or mobile phone display in sunlight. This question is more about engineering so have to refine this somehow. It consists of novel ideas such as:

1. **[?]** get a display that I can use in sun -light
2. **[optics, mechanics, other?]** develop glasses that helps to see in sunglight (no need to modify then displays).
3. **[optics]** develop hat that blocks sun-light and somehow helps to see colors better
4. **[nano-technology, other?]** perhaps some nano-processed material that absorb certain frequency better?
5. **[aberraction, reflection, optics, other?]** have the display in your glasses but reflection/aberration/etc problem still
6. other ideas?

There are hacks such as [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FX4Z44) but I would like to find a better solution. I am not sure whether it exist. How can I break this issue into parts to make it more appropriate to Physics.SE? Please, add fields in brackets to which the ideas may be related, thank you.

Comment: Honestly, this whole thing sounds more engineering-related. I won't close this or anything, so in case anyone does want to help you polish up your question, they're free to do it, but I wouldn't expect too much.